# XML Schema - Key constraint on two two elements

Tags: xml, xsd, schema, xmlschemaset

My .xml file is something like this:

```
<root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="file.xsd">
  <parent id="">
    <child>
      <part>A1</part>
    </child>
  </parent>
  <another-parent name="AAA">
    <part name="A1"/>
    <part name="A2"/>
    <part name="A3"/>
  </another-parent>
  <another-parent name="BBB">
    <part name="A1"/>
  </another-parent>
</root>
```

What I want is:

1. `name` of `<another-parent>` must be unique. And it is ok.
2. `name` of `<part>` must be unique within `name` of `<another-parent>` is placed. And it is ok.
3. `<part name="A1">` inside `<child>` must be a keyref of `<another-parent>`.  And I can't do that.

For the first point, I used the following and it works properly.

```
<xsd:key name="anotherParentKey">
    <xsd:selector xpath="another-parent"/>
    <xsd:field xpath="@name"/>
</xsd:key>
```

For the second one I used this one in the  element declaration:

```
<xsd:key name="partKey">
    <xsd:selector xpath="part"/>
    <xsd:field xpath="./@name"/>
</xsd:key>
```

It works now.

But for the third part, I tried to put this code in the  (the first common ancestor) but it doesnt work:

```
<xsd:keyref name="roadSegmentRef" refer="roadSegmentKey">
    <xsd:selector xpath="identifiedEntity/place/roadSegment" />
    <xsd:field xpath="." />
</xsd:keyref>
```

But what I get is only:

```
cvc-identity-constraint.4.3: Key 'partRef' with value 'A1' not found for identity constraint of element 'parent'.   file.xml    /sheet/xsd  line 19 XML Problem
```

Comment: Please tell us what you tried, and how it failed. Otherwise the only thing we can do is to write a tutorial on key/unique/keyref, and there are plenty of those already. (StackOverflow posts should *ask a question*, not ask for people to write the code for you.)

Comment: Okay, sorry. I edited my post above

Answer (score 0):

You haven't shown us WHERE you put these declarations, and my guess is that you put them in the wrong place.

If you want every X within some Y to have a unique value for Z, then your key/unique declarations need to go in the element declaration for Y; the selector needs to select X starting from Y, and the fields need to select Z starting from X.

Comment: I solved for the 1) and 2). But the 3) doesn't work. I edited my message with changes and added where I put them.

Comment: I'm not sure precisely what your schema now looks like but I suspect that the key and keyref are not in the same element declaration. That's allowed, but the rules are incredibly complicated and it's a situation I prefer to avoid at all costs. I know it would take me half an hour to investigate, so sorry, I don't have the time.